# Data Explorer currently crashing Internet Explorer

Tags: bug, status-completed, data-explorer, internet-explorer

Right now when I go to http://data.stackexchange.com (either by link or typing in the URL) in Internet Explorer 8 on Vista, it crashes the tab and IE attempts to recover twice, finishing with res://ieframe.dll/acr_error.htm#stackexchange.com,https://data.stackexchange.com/

<sub>I need to RDP or get up to check what's happening with Chrome on XP and I don't want to at the moment :-)</sub>

Comment: why are you using IE8 btw ?

Comment: @waffles: It's my fathers laptop. Windows Update has twice "automatically" ( :-) ) upgraded to IE9, but he's too used to the IE8 interface with Favorites on the left and the separate search box, he's demanded I uninstall it.

Comment: Of course, in my work environment I'm still working on XP and Server 2003, so I've got no upgrade path for IE there.

Comment: BTW On Server2K3 in IE8 I was able to open the Data Explorer home page, but it then crashed with effectively a NullReference exception when I went to my user page. (And repeating this for this comment, it crashed immediately from the home page, suggesting the intermittency mentioned below.) Here I _can_ debug it in VS2010, and on a quick look, when the call to `CMarkup::EnsureTopElems` when called from `CLinkElement::HandleLinkedObjects` returns 0 in EAX, or [EAX+4]=0 as seems to be the case here, this will occur. In fact a work around in the debugger is: restart at the following mov eax,edx.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This ended up being a bug with the [MVC Mini Profiler](http://code.google.com/p/mvc-mini-profiler/), which is active on [Data Explorer](http://data.stackexchange.com).

The MVC Mini Profiler tries to inject its stylesheet into the page as part of its initialization routine by creating (via jQuery) a `<link>` element from a string with `rel` and `type` attributes. It then attempts to set the `href` attribute to point to the stylesheet.

IE 8, for reasons unknown, seems to get extremely upset and crashes the tab when you attempt to set the value of the `href` attribute or property when `rel="stylesheet"` was previously set via `innerHTML`. Creating the link a bit differently prevents the crash, although then IE 8 runs into some additional errors I haven't finished debugging yet. Once I figure out what else is going on I'll throw together patches for the respective issues.

Comment: +1 for debugging IE problems.  Glad someone is able to...  : D

Comment: wow ... ie is so damn special, let me know if you have a patch I pull it into mvc mini profiler

Comment: @waffles Patch for this issue [can be found here](http://code.google.com/r/tmslft-mvcmp/source/detail?r=6c9840aaea15d70508d434584cc031c809be2f2a) (just built the `<link>` without `innerHTML`), but still troubles in IE 8...when templates are cached in `localStorage` and added to the body immediately, it can't find `#profileTemplate` which causes chaos...still looking into why/what can be done.

Comment: (likely only happens if the `fetchResults()` request is super-fast, since it was intermittent for me)

Answer (score 2):

Wow, IE is odd:

As Tim pointed out, this is a mini profiler bug, I just patched it so IE renders the mini profiler properly and IE7 renders the little giblet in the corner.

Related is: [Dynamically loading css stylesheet doesn't work on IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1184950/dynamically-loading-css-stylesheet-doesnt-work-on-ie)

Will try to get a patch deployed later today

Comment: Oh, aside from the [template issue](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/121524/data-explorer-currently-crashing-internet-explorer#comment322290_121549) there was also a [NPE condition](http://code.google.com/r/tmslft-mvcmp/source/detail?r=e3294abd9513eb233f92fc74cd1f4ded0f4ea81c) in IE 8 after I fixed the stylesheet crash, forgot about that.

Comment: @TimStone yeah fixed that as well

Comment: @TimStone see: https://github.com/SamSaffron/MiniProfiler/commit/6d9f9da05c1478174e521252d099d7077a1d897a

Comment: Ah, fantastic :)